# Is there a value for $K$, for which there exists a straight line which is perpendicular with the three planes

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is there a value for $K$, for which there exists a straight line $x = at$, $y = bt$, $z = ct$  which is perpendicular with the three planes
>
> \begin{align}2x - (k + 2)y + z + 1 &= 0\\
> kx + 2y - 4z - 3 &= 0\\
> kx - y - 3z + 3 &= 0\end{align}
>
> If so give $K$ and the vector $(a, b, c)^T$

Not really sure how to accomplish this. I tried solving the equations and got that $y = \frac{21}{10}$ and $z = \frac3{10}$ which showed that either $k$ or $x$ is $0$, then I plugged that into the first equation and got that $k = -\frac{29}{21}$

Not sure if I'm way off track or how to proceed.

Comment: Use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to properly format equations

Comment: Another way to approach this problem is to note that the vector perpendicular to a plane has entries equal to the coefficients of $x,y,z$ in the equations. So just see if there is a value of $k$ so that each normal vector is proportional to the other.

Comment: @OsamaGhani I'm sorry I don't really understand. I'm not sure what to make of  x = at, y = bt, z = ct as well.

Answer (score 0):

If there were a line perpendicular to all three of these planes, then they would have to be parallel planes. So they should have equation of form $$Ax+By+Cz=D$$ for different values of $D$. Clearly the equation of planes do not have this form and so no such value of $k$ exists.

Added:

The vectors normal to the given three planes form the following matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
2&k&k\\
-k-2&2&-1\\
1&-4&-3
\end{pmatrix}
whose column space must be one-dimensional for them to be parallel. But its ref shows that it has pivot positions in two columns irrespective of the value of $k$, so the column space is at least two dimensional.

Comment: Is it that simple? I find it hard to believe this assignment not having any solution due to it being a big part of my task.